# Have to run sudo dhclient eth0 automatically every boot

Tags: network-manager, dhcp, ipv6

I just installed ubuntu 12.04.1 alternative install (for raid 0 on some disks). I Have some problems with the net. I'm at school, we use cable, and it got IPv6.

If I `run ifconfig eth0` heres my output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:cb:4e:87:ff:db  
          inet addr:128.39.194.217  Bcast:128.39.194.223  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: 2001:700:1100:8008:e2cb:4eff:fe87:ffdb/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::e2cb:4eff:fe87:ffdb/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:700:1100:8008:48f7:c23:1d87:da6c/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1063378 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:489811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1577173461 (1.5 GB)  TX bytes:37043669 (37.0 MB)
          Interrupt:68 Base address:0x6000
```

My /etc/network/interfaces look like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
# NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp
# NetworkManager#hostname 2001:700:1100:1::4
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

(I had to remove the hash tags, because of the BIGFONT i get on ask ubuntu)

The "network manager" says that I'm not connected.

Let me know if you need any more information. :)

Comment: comment all lines except `auto lo` and 
`iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: what "Sudo dhclient eth0" does??

Comment: An easy solution https://askubuntu.com/a/1499227/1582790

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok so I have a way better answer then I had before.

How about we try this.

Open a terminal.

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add: `sudo dhclient eth0` like so.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sudo dhclient eth0
exit 0
```

Save & Close. Reboot and should work.

Comment: Just make sure you place it before `exit 0` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Glad to see that it worked for you.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in rc.local

Comment: /sbin/dhclient eth0 (use full path to binary in some distro)

Answer (score 3):

Your NetworkManager has for some reason *commented out* the necessary configuration to make DHCP pick up an IPv4 address. Maybe it was a bug or you configured it to turn off IPv4? This is why it isn't working.

```
# NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

To resolve the problem, simply restore the configuration.

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Also check your NetworkManager configuration and make sure you didn't disable IPv4 on the interface.

Comment: Where can you access these settings?

Comment: @CodyBugstein You can use `nmcli` to manage NetworkManager.

Comment: Can you explain how I can edit it to include `iface eth0 inet dhcp` ? Sorry I'm a noob :(

Comment: @CodyBugstein I thought you were asking about NetworkManager? The setting you named is located in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a launcher for your command then put it in the autostartup applications

To create a launcher:

Using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> type

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will launch the  GUI Dialog and create a launcher on your Desktop:

[image]

**Prerequisites**

`gnome-desktop-item-edit` is installed automatically if you have installed gnome-shell/gnome-fallback.  It is also installed automatically if you have previously installed `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Alternatively, you can install the old gnome-panel without much of the bulk:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

Comment: Come on! 
You also need to setup a passwordless sudo for that command. 
Those startup applications are loaded only after login and this is not what the user wants.

Answer (score -1):

uess it is back to the drawing board.This download is faulty.  /etc/Network does not exit. None of the solutions presented will work.  I guess it is back to thee shopping for a package that will install on teh Pi 3B+.